# Concept of knots in B-splines

Tags: terminology, spline

> Given $n+1$ control points, B-spline blending functions are polynomials
>   of degree $d-1$, $(1<d\leq n+1)$.

This much is easy to comprehend.

Now comes the part I am not able to make any sense of.

> Each polynomial function is defined over $d$ subintervals of the total
>   range of $u$. The selected set of subinterval endpoints $u_j$ is referred
>   to as a **knot vector**.

What is the purpose of **knot vector**? What is its physical significance?